# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) Swift on macOS appp

Tags: ios, swift, macos

In the following line there is a function that I call from another file.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     
        var result = myFunc()
        
        
       
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

The function works successfully, but when it finishes, I get a result like this.

*In AppDelegate* **@main Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)**

The code snippet that caused the crash:

```
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: textureURL.deletingLastPathComponent(), withIntermediateDirectories: true)
                } catch {
                    print("Couldn't create output directory")
                    print(error)
                    return false
                }

                guard let texture = textureSampler.texture else {
                    continue
                }

                let cgImage = texture.imageFromTexture()!.takeRetainedValue()
                let nsBitmap = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: cgImage)

                var imageType: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType
                let textureType = textureURL.pathExtension.lowercased()

                switch(textureType) {
                    case "png":
                        imageType = .png
                    case "jpg", "jpeg":
                        imageType = .jpeg
                    default:
                        print("Unknown texture type \"\(textureType)\" of texture \(textureURL.lastPathComponent)")
                        imageType = .png
                }

                if convertToPNG {
                    // override automatic selection here
                    imageType = .png
                    textureURL = textureURL.deletingPathExtension().appendingPathExtension("png")
                }

                let imageData = nsBitmap.representation(using: imageType, properties: [
                    NSBitmapImageRep.PropertyKey.compressionFactor: NSNumber(floatLiteral: 1.0)
                ])!

                do {
                    try imageData.write(to: textureURL)
                    alreadySaved.append(textureURL)
                } catch {
                    print("Couldn't save \(textureURL.lastPathComponent)")
                    return false
                }
```

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to get a helpful answer without sharing the code of  myFunc.

Comment: Share `myFunc()` just in case. Also, could you share with us the content of Console output? There might be some useful information thee...

Comment: The interesting thing is that when I run this function one after another, it doesn't give an error, but whenever this code finishes running, the application crashes.

Comment: It probably means that once it finishes, your code attempts to access something that has since been released from memory. Check if you're not retaining a self in a closure or something like that. Also move your "result" variable declaration from inside viewDidLoad to a property at the root of the class.

Comment: There's a lot of force unwraps here, it's pretty hard to narrow down what the issue is without you: trimming down the example to its bare essence, 2: providing much more detail on the error (the error message, the line it's on, the backtrace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution;
[in apple sandbox documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxQuickStart/AppSandboxQuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH2-SW3)

> If the app crashes when you attempt to run it, specifically by receiving an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION signal, the most likely reason is that you previously ran a sandboxed app with the same bundle identifier but a different code signature. This crashing upon launch is an App Sandbox security feature that prevents one app from masquerading as another and thereby gaining access to the other app’s container.

And then change this line

```
let cgImage = texture.imageFromTexture()!.takeRetainedValue()
```

as below

```
let cgImage = texture.imageFromTexture()!.takeUnretainedValue()
```